# awk $0 and $1 behaves differently when run from file vs run from bash

Tags: ubuntu, awk

I don't know if this is a feature of awk or not but `$0` and `$1` behave differently if I use an awk program file and use the `-f` vs if I use the same command on the `bash command line`.

Take the following test file:

```
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a,bc, x
```

When I use the following command on the bash command line:

```
awk "{ print $1 }" sample_input.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a b c , e,f
a,bc, x
```

As you can see this is the output of $0 and not $1. $0 just outputs blank lines.

Now when I use the same command in an awk command I get the correct output:

```
{ print $1 }
awk -f test.awk sample_input.txt

a
a
a
a
a
a,bc,
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. **Is this some weird feature of `awk` ?**

Comment: Because it's in a double quoted string (`"..."`), the `$1` will be expanded by the shell, probably to _nothing_. Put the awk script inside _single_ quotes: `awk '{ print $1 }' sample_input.txt`

Comment: @mosvy How are double quoted strings handled by bash ?

Comment: [double quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes)

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not some weird feature of `awk` but instead due to the ordinary way that the shell treats variables in double quotes.

In the command

```
awk "{ print $1 }" sample_input.txt
```

the shell would, since the `awk` code is double quoted, replace `$1` with the value of the first positional parameter (usually the first command line argument given to a script or shell function).  If this value is empty or unset, your `awk` script then becomes

```
awk "{ print }" sample_input.txt
```

which has the same effect as

```
cat sample_input.txt
```

To prevent the shell from expanding `$1`, single quote the `awk` script:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' sample_input.txt
```

The behaviour of the shell with regards to double and single quotes is described by the POSIX standard:

> Enclosing characters in single-quotes ( `''` ) shall preserve the literal value of each character within the single-quotes. A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes.
>
> Enclosing characters in double-quotes ( `""` ) shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters backquote, `<dollar-sign>`, and `<backslash>`, as follows:
>
> `$`
>
> > **The `<dollar-sign>` shall retain its special meaning introducing parameter expansion** (see Parameter Expansion), a form of command substitution (see Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (see Arithmetic Expansion).
>
> [...]

(https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02)

Comment: Could you explain how double quoted strings are handled by Bash ?

Comment: @ng.newbie Things that looks like shell variables in single quoted strings are not expanded by the shell. Things that looks like shell variable in double quoted strings _are_ expanded by the shell.  In your `awk` code, `$1` should not be interperted as a shell variable but as something that `awk` should use. It therefore needs to be passed to `awk` as the literal string `$1`, untouched by the shell.

Comment: @ng.newbie It's similar to wanting to print the string `$hello` (`$` followed by `hello`, not some variable `$hello`) with `echo`. Try `echo "$hello"` vs. `echo '$hello'`.